# MYSQL LEFT(column, 100) and PHP {$row[(column)]}

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table with a text field named "body" and a title field named "title".
I want to choose the first 100 characters of the text field "body" by like this:

```
$query="SELECT title, LEFT(body, 100) FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

and then output the result in a web page:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "...html... {$row["title"]} ...html... {$row["body"]} ...html...";
}
```

but I get an error: "Notice: Undefined index: body in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 299"
Can somebody help?
Thanks.

Comment: You can see what's happening if you do `print_r( $row );` (which, quite frankly, should instinctively be the first debugging step in all cases like this).

Comment: You are not escaping your echo'd output, use `{hmtlentities($row['title'])}` to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: thanks for the warning Johan but when I try this I get: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 287

Answer (score 2):

You need to rename your field with an alias when you apply functions like `LEFT()` to it, otherwise you have no easy way to reference it by name.

```
SELECT title, LEFT(body, 100) AS body FROM table
                              ^^^^^^^ give name to field
```

Now your reference to `{$row["body"]}` should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to name your field or access it with `LEFT(body, 100)` if you apply some function:

```
$query = "SELECT title, LEFT(body, 100) as body FROM table";
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing that creates an unnamed column. Just add an alias:

```
$query="SELECT title, LEFT(body, 100) AS BODY FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```